# On button click can MS Access change an entry without specific user input?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created a library system which lists books, sorts if they are available and allows loans and returns etc.

In the 'book details' table there is a column for if the book is available which has two options, "Available" and "Borrowed".

I use this so that when a book is being searched for in the loans form only the available books are shown.

Is it possible (and if so how do I do it) to change the status of the book from available to borrowed and visa-versa without the user having to manually tell the database.
I.e. when loaning a book when the 'loan' button is pushed the status changes to borrowed and when returning a book when the 'return book' button is pushed the status changes to available? At the moment these buttons record the transaction that has happened and then updates that transaction to show that the book has been returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DoCmd.RunSQL` method to write an action query which updates your values.

Your `LoanButton_Click()` procedure would include something like:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tblBookDetails SET Status = 'Borrowed' WHERE BookID = '" & cboBookID.Value & "'"
```

Similary your `ReturnButton_Click()` procedure would include:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tblBookDetails SET Status = 'Available' WHERE BookID = '" & cboBookID.Value & "'"
```

I'm guessing at the names of your tables, columns, controls etc. but you should get the idea.